# blur every object behind itself

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blur

sorry I am a new guy here and in illustrator, I am gonna make a low opacity and blur object that effects on every object behind itself.
like below finally 
[image]

Comment: What have you tried? But no elementary this can not be done, you can do it in a convoluted manner but it will not do what you want.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor yes but it relies on copying, ist not a oject that blurs what is behind. But that the best you can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain it so it's easy to follow.

- Duplicate the image and paste in front of itself <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Draw a square polygon the size I want the blur to be
- Select both my new polygon and the image I duplicated and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> to create a clipping mask
- Then to this new group, I would apply a gaussian blur

Comment: something else, when I blue the square polygon, it is out of shape, out of its frame you know, it no longer has its sharp edge

Comment: @FaridS Thats why you need a mask as described in link of Ovaryraptor's comment Point is that object blurs itself, if you want to blur others blur a group or something and opacity mask or clip it with object

Comment: I think you must apply the blur to the picture only before masking.

Comment: and your fill object must be bigger than your clip. But as i said not exactly a object that blurs what is behind it.

Comment: I've done it. I swear I just forgot it :D. tnx